# Redirect all file IO in Windows

Tags: windows, redirect, file-io, virtualfilesystem

I'm using a virtual file system (PhysFS) and I'd like the entire application to do file IO through this VFS (that includes third-party libraries).

How can I redirect all file IO operations (C `FILE*` objects and C++ streams) through this VFS in Windows?

Also, a related question. Is file IO redirection a common feature of OS APIs? Will it be easy for me to port my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API hooking is probably the only way to address the problem. Hooking can be done using third-party helper libraries such as [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) and some other. This method is both non-trivial and not portable. In theory you could use a filesystem filter driver, but this way is much more complicated and requires a kernel-mode driver (which is a PITA to develop).

Comment: It's not a problem per se, just that it would make the code a lot nicer. But it seems the effort required to do this isn't justified in my case.